# How to put new lines in p tag in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, next.js, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable div, whenever I insert a new line by pressing enter or shift+enter the new line is a textNode in the div but I want the new line to be in `p` element.

I want a simple solution

I am using React Js so I save the content of contentEditable div in a state named `content` updated by `onChange` and I'm using `react-contenteditable` component package

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
    const insertNewLine = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Create a new <p> element
            const newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
            newParagraph.innerHTML = '<br>'; // Add a line break to make the new paragraph visible

            // Insert the new <p> element after the current selection
            const selection = window.getSelection();
            const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(newParagraph);

            // Move the caret inside the new <p> element
            const newRange = document.createRange();
            newRange.setStart(newParagraph, 0);
            newRange.setEnd(newParagraph, 0);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(newRange);
        }
    };
```